# How can I properly query a database multiple times for a value if the first time it didn't find anything C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

I'm building a Car Management app using Xamarin, and my Back End is an ASP.NET Web API. I have a large dataset of cars where I can find the price of the car by Make, Name, Year, Odometer and Engine Capacity. I have tried to average most of the values so I can find data, but many times it just doesn't return anything. So I decided to try and query the database multiple times, but each time it doesn't return anything, I either turn a value into an interval (eg. odometer = 100000 and then odometer >= 80000 && odometer <= 120000). It kinda works like this, but I don't think it's the right way to write it. I was thinking about Strategy Pattern, but can't figure out how to apply in my case.

What I have tried is to make Repository where I get the car object, and then I have six methods that just query the database, each gradually with fewer parameters. There are a lot of If Elses.

```cs
public GetCarPriceResponse GetPrice(GetCarPriceRequest car)
        {
            var price = new GetCarPriceResponse
            {
                Errors = new List<string>()
            };

            if (GetPriceFirst(car) == null)
                if (GetPriceSecond(car) == null)
                    if (GetPriceThird(car) == null)
                        if (GetPriceFourth(car) == null)
                            if (GetPriceFifth(car) == null)
                                if (GetPriceSixth(car) == null)
                                {
                                    price.Success = false;
                                    price.Errors.Add("Could not find car 
price");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    price = GetPriceSixth(car);
                                }
                            else price = GetPriceFifth(car);
                        else price = GetPriceFourth(car);
                    else price = GetPriceThird(car);
                else price = GetPriceSecond(car);
            else price = GetPriceFirst(car);

            price.Success = true;

            return price;
        }
```

The first function looks like this:

```
public GetCarPriceResponse GetPriceFirst(GetCarPriceRequest car)
        {
            var prices = _context.CarPrices.Where(p =>
                p.make == car.make &&
                p.model == car.model &&
                p.year == car.year &&
                p.CC == car.CC &&
                p.odometer == car.odometer).ToList();

            if (prices.Count == 0) return null;
            return CalculateAveragePrice(prices);
        }
```

And the third one like this:

```
public GetCarPriceResponse GetPriceThird(GetCarPriceRequest car)
        {
            var differenceDown = 0;
            var differenceUp = 0;

            if (car.odometer < 50000)
            {
                differenceDown = 0;
                differenceUp = 50000;
            }
            else if (car.odometer > 50000)
            {
                differenceDown = 50000;
                differenceUp = 50000;
            }
            else if (car.odometer > 215000)
            {
                differenceDown = 50000;
                differenceUp = 0;
            }

            var prices = _context.CarPrices.Where(p =>
                p.make == car.make &&
                p.model == car.model &&
                p.year == car.year &&
                p.CC == car.CC &&
                p.odometer >= car.odometer - differenceDown &&
                p.odometer <= car.odometer + differenceUp).ToList();

            if (prices.Count == 0) return null;
            return CalculateAveragePrice(prices);
        }
```

In the fourth one I completely eliminate the odometer parameter, and in the sixth one I query a different database that has an average price based on odometer, engine capacity and model year.
This is the fifth method:

```
 public GetCarPriceResponse GetPriceFifth(GetCarPriceRequest car)
        {
            var prices = _context.CarPrices.Where(p =>
                p.make == car.make &&
                p.model == car.model &&
                p.year >= car.year - 2 &&
                p.year <= car.year + 2 &&
                p.CC == car.CC).ToList();

            if (prices.Count == 0) return null;
            return CalculateAveragePrice(prices);
        }
```

It works fine for now, but for example if you add an electric car, with the engine capacity of 0, it does not function properly and such. 
But I am asking if there is a way to make this code better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to find a single car each time have the query return a list of cars that match `make`, `model`, `year` and `CC` (since that seems to be the common criteria) and sort the results by odometer value.  Your app can then look through the list (using a local LINQ query) to find the best match in the list.

Trying to query for a single match multiple times is going to be way too slow due to all of the network traffic.